# Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates

Tags: camera, opencv, firmware, raspi-config

Trying to get the pi cam working with open cv per http://thinkrpi.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/opencvpi-cam-step-5-basic-use-display-a-picture/.  Finally have the program built, but now I get this:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/camcv $ ./camcv
mmal: main: Failed to create preview component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

I've done sudo apt-get upgrade/update, sudo rpi-update, and ensured camera was enabled within raspi-config.  I can capture images with raspistill well enough, although apparently I can do this even with the camera not enabled in raspi-config.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the problem.  The wordpress posting uses an obsolete codebase which does not work with the most recent OpenCV code, particularly in main()'s call to raspipreview_create().  The preview was created successfully, but the success code was interpreted wrong to log the error shown above.  I modified the original RaspiStill.c code as the article directed instead.  Had to do some finagling beyond what the article posted, but nothing a little DDD couldn't fix.